# Solr search query time increases as the start keeps on increasing

Tags: java, solr

I have currently over 25 million documents in Solr and the volume will gradually increase. I need to search for the records over such big size of Solr indexes. The query response time is low when the start is low, e.g 0. But as the start increases, e.g 100000 , searching in Solr is also taking time. How can i make the search faster even with high start number over large data sets in Solr? The rows remain constant only the start keeps on increasing. I don't want the response time to increase as the start keeps on increasing instead want the result returned for `start=100000` should take the same time as for `start=0` with say suppose `rows=1000` as this is performance issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If thought over this for a while, could you give some more detail, why you want to go that deep into a result? Most people I know do not read the 1.000th entry of a result, they start over a better search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is called `Deep Paging`. There is [a good article about it](http://solr.pl/en/2011/07/18/deep-paging-problem/) on [solr.pl](http://solr.pl/en) and [an incomplete issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1726) on Solr's tracker.

The solution mentioned in the article will require you to sort your result, if that is not feasible for you the solution will not work. The idea is to sort by a stable attribute, in the article that is `price` and then filter with a price range, like `fq=price:[9000+TO+10000]`.

If you combine that `fq` with a suitable `start` - like `start=100030` - you will get better performance, as solr will not collect the documents that do not match the `fq`.

But you will need to make at least one query in advance to fetch the suitable meta data, like how many docs have been found at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I doubt the use of filter query in the application as i am only doing text indexing and the queries are more kind of `AND` or `OR` rather than the range query. The Solr's tracker solution is something that i am actually looking for but it is incomplete and don't see any good work around related to this.

Comment: It does not matter what your query is like. The question is whether you need to sort by relevance or not to use the fq-technique.

Comment: I do not need to use fq-technique. However, I am accepting your answer as this might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Solr 4.7 a new feature has been introduced `Cursors`. This has been done exactly to address the problem of Deep Paging. If you still have the problem and you may perform the upgrade to Solr 4.7 this is the best option for you.

Some references about deep paging with Solr

- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/pagination-of-results.html#performance-problems-with-deep-paging